# How to manage a client list in MPI client/server mode

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I am trying to implement an MPI program which is to have a server node assign task pieces to client node, but I am a freshman and don't know how to mange the client list, can anyone help me?

Let me describe it more specify:

Server node:

```
MPI_COMM clients[4]; // store client communicators, but I am not sure this is correct or not!
```

Several clients connect to server using `mpirun -np 1 ./mpiclient` more than one time, not processor greater than 1.

The reason I want to do this is I want to send each client different job to calculate.

Question 2:  How can I get the attributes of the client?

For example: `MPI_Comm_accept(portname,MPI_INFO_NULL,0,MPI_COMM_SELF,&client);`
How can I get client name or ip?

Comment: MPI jobs are inherently distributed. Connecting a client to a server is a collective operation, i.e. it involves all ranks of the client job, therefore there is no single hostname or IP associated with a job, even when the client is a singleton. I am not aware of any portable mechanism in MPI to obtain such identification. You should treat the intercommunicator as the ID of the client.

Comment: Are you sure that you really want/need to use `MPI_Comm_connect`/`MPI_Comm_accept`? Most of the time, people using MPI start up all of the processes at the beginning of the job `mpirun -np 5 ./mpiapp` and designate certain ranks to do certain things. While you *can* do MPMD with MPI, it's not where I'd start.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that there's a best practice here, but there are a few options.

1. **Know your list of IP addresses ahead of time.**

Most of the time, people have a cluster set up with a static pool of IP addresses. That means its easy to predict who will be connecting so you can call `MPI_COMM_ACCEPT` for each IP address and the clients will already know the address of the "server".

2. **Don't use Connect/Accept directly**

It may not be necessary to go through the pain of managing all of your connections directly. You might be able to do something else like `MPI_COMM_SPAWN(_MULTIPLE)` and spawn your children directly from your master. This simplifies managing connections, though you still have to deal with some of the weirdness of dynamic processing in MPI, specifically inter-communciators.

3. **Don't use dynamic processes at all**

Many times, people coming into distributed programming, and specifically MPI, for the first time still have a sockets frame of reference. Meaning, they expect to have to set up all of their own connections and communication management. In reality, MPI and other communication libraries are designed to be slightly higher level than that and let you ignore some of the mundane communication management and get straight to passing data around. Usually in an MPI job, you will use a single binary for your program and have each process decide what they'll be doing based on their rank. For example:

```
mpirun -np 5 ./my_prog

...
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

if (rank == 0) {
    /* Distribute work */
} else {
    /* Get work from rank 0 */
}
...
```

It's also possible to run multiple binaries this way if you want to separate out your codes for different parts of the program. How you run this can vary from implementation to implementation, but with MPICH, it works like this:

```
mpiexec -n 1 ./my_prog1 : -n 4 ./my_prog2
```

Then `my_prog1` would distribute the work to all of the other processes running `my_prog2`. In this model, all processes still end up in the same `MPI_COMM_WORLD` so they can just check their rank at the beginning of the program and get working.

Comment: Thanks Wesley. But how can I manage the client? I tried to use &rank in the server aspect to distinguish which client it is, but rank doesn't refer to the client.  And I tried to use worldSize(from MPI_Comm_size) to get how many client will have in total, but always get 1(I guess it is refer to server processor )

Comment: MPI doesn't have a notion of which machine a rank is running on. It's supposed to be hardware agnostic by the time you get into the application.